# How to right adjust the output of a print statement

Tags: output-formatting

Suppose  i want to print  numbers in a loop/table
For[n = 1, n < 31, n++, Print[BaseForm[n ,7]]]

the output comes with numbers left adjusted. How Can I make them right adjusted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `Column` and `Alignment`:

```
Column[BaseForm[#, 7] & /@ Range[30], Alignment -> Right]
```

which produces the following right-adjusted output:

[image]

> Thanks, how would you make a multi-column. Say I also want to print i in base 5 in a second column?

Try this:

```
Grid[Outer[BaseForm[#1, #2] &, Range[30], Range[2, 16]], Alignment -> Right]
```

which produces this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how would  you make a multi-column. Say I also want to print  i in base  5 in a second column?

Comment: @Maesumi: I edited my answer to do multi-columns.